# Is there an equivalent to get_focus() in Tkinter for <"Enter">?

Tags: tkinter, widget, hover, focus, enter

In Tkinter for the event <"FocusIn"> (which you can bind to a widget), you have like the "reversed" function .get_focus(), which will show you the name of the widget, which has the focus at the moment.
For the event <"Enter"> (which means that the mouse cursor is hovering over some widget) is there an equivalent "reverse" function? Something like ".get_entered()" or similar, to show you the name of the widget that the mouse cursor is hovering over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which widget is under the cursor you can use the `winfo_containing` method.

```
x, y = root.winfo_pointerxy()
widget = root.winfo_containing(x,y)
```

Comment: That was the perfect answer! Thank you very much! 
May I additionally ask you: For me this information was especially hard to find on the internet, yet you seemed to know it just like that. Where did you learn that information? Was it from a tkinter book?

Comment: I've been programming with the tk toolkit since 1995 or so, so it's largely just experience. All features of tk are documented in the [tk man pages](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/contents.htm) which I've read many, many times.